# Exchange 2010 EMS - Total size of users mailboxes within a particular OU

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell

I'm doing some massive DB cleanups at the moment. We have two DBs both approaching 400GB and I'm wanting to split the DB's into departments.

To do that I need to know the total size of mailboxes within an OU. I've run this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796101/exchange-listing-mailboxes-in-an-ou-with-their-mailbox-size but this only gives me a list and I need a combined totalitemsize so know how big I need the new DB's to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=local" | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select @{Name="Size";Expression={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}} | Measure Size -Sum -Min -Max -Average
```

Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In exchange management shell, you can do this:

```
$totalsize = 0
$mbxs = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=local"
$mbxs | Foreach-Object { $totalsize += (Get-MailboxStatistics $_).TotalItemSize }
$totalsize
```

In my org, this reports as:

```
                                            IsUnlimited Value
                                            ----------- -----
                                                  False 11.29 GB (12,121,419,924 bytes)
```

How does this fare for you?

Comment: Hi John

Not good, if I run this as a .ps1 then it returns '0'.

Comment: Did you try just entering the commands one by one? Plus, I did update as one of the variables had an incorrect name.

Comment: And did you specify the OU, the one I gave was for demo purposes?

Comment: I've tried this: `Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=local" | Foreach-Object { $totalsize += (Get-MailboxStatistics $_).TotalItemSize }` - replacing the OU and I get an error pertaining to a pipeline already executing.

Comment: That's because the mailboxes are still being gathered, I think? Try using the variables in my example.

Comment: Or something funky is going on in the Get-Mailbox CMDlet.

Comment: I think I've found something: `get-mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "OU=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=local" | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select @{Name="Size";Expression={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}} | Measure Size -Sum -Min -Max -Average` - And I'm assuming the Sum field on the output is the size I'm after. And in fact if I change MB to GB in `ToMB` then I get a number that makes sense.

Comment: Sounds ever so complicated but if it works for you then I would create an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9489/discussion-between-john-and-moif-murphy)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$totalsize = 0

$mbxs = Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit "yourOU"
$mbxs | Foreach-Object { $totalsize += (Get-MailboxStatistics $_).TotalItemSize.value.tobytes() }

$totalsize

$totalsize/1GB
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, Get-MailboxStatistics output just a display name - not unique and cant really be used as such. The other half of the information you need is in Get-Mailbox :- found answer in following link. once you have the data on all your mailboxes, and the output can be IMPORTED into excel you can do all your sorting etc and delete whatever you dont want

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_27828458.html

```
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{
 $Mailbox | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "MailboxSizeMB" -Value ((Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMb())
}
$Mailboxes | Sort-Object MailboxSizeMB -Desc | Select PrimarySMTPAddress, MailboxSizeMB


#REM - to export this out -- do the following ;) enjoy (see the part where it says "Select" you can add additional fields like ALIAS etc to this)

$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited
foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{
 $Mailbox | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "MailboxSizeMB" -Value ((Get-MailboxStatistics $Mailbox).TotalItemSize.Value.ToMb())
}
$Mailboxes | Sort-Object MailboxSizeMB -Desc | Select PrimarySMTPAddress, MailboxSizeMB | Export-Csv -NoType "C:\temp\Mailboxessize.csv"
```